# How do I return values from a React component?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, reactjs

I made a slider component, using JQueryUI, which internally computes its current slider value. I am rendering it like this:

```
<Slider config={config} value={this.getValue} />
```

Inside the slider component I call this `getValue()` function and pass the current slider value:

```
this.props.value(this.state.sliderValue);
```

In the jsx file where I rendered the component I can only retrieve the value of the slider inside the callback function getValue(). Is there any way I can directly get the value instead of inside the callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure poking inside an Object is a wise idea. if the calling objects need to know of the inside of Slider than pushing the value up via a callback, and returning it down with a "value=" is the right thing to do. read about the difference of controlled vs uncontrolled objects in react: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

p.s use value={this.getValue.bind(this)} that way getValue can save it to *this* so other methods can use it if needed

Answer (score 2):

You can use a reference to the mounted component to get its state:

```
var Slider = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      sliderValue: 5
    };
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div />;
  }
});

var mySlider = ReactDOM.render(<Slider />, document.body);
console.log(mySlider.state.sliderValue);
```

See more about using [refs to components in the React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html).